# SQL - Selecting the 6th visit from a customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to be able to report on clients that visited my business 6 times, the 6th time being today.

I've got this so far, but this won't pick up someone who had visited a total of 5 times yesterday, and then twice today.

```
SELECT Member_FullName, Branch_Name, Member_Email1, Account_Description, Visit_LastVisitDateOnly
FROM   View1
WHERE (Visit_TotalVisits = '6')
  AND (Visit_LastVisitDateOnly = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Rows from the visits table (was asked structure of table)

```
VisitID BranchID    MemberID    AccountID   Visit
BF98FAC1-F430-47AD-B810-02744A1633EA    C4E833C0-7675-4650-8D58-F64DF87BB0F2    E90EC99B-8C15-4F01-AEFC-60430BE4B6BF    C404B81D-85C5-42D1-8FD2-52657960FD9A    2015-11-20 16:00:00.000
5C0CB2F0-3ED9-441F-A789-03B679FF85E7    C4E833C0-7675-4650-8D58-F64DF87BB0F2    E90EC99B-8C15-4F01-AEFC-60430BE4B6BF    C404B81D-85C5-42D1-8FD2-52657960FD9A    2015-11-20 16:00:00.000
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...) The answer may depend on product used.

Comment: Using SQL Management studio 2012, and I do have a Visits table, which logs each visit based on a UI of Visit_ID - this query is pulling from a view that uses the Visits table.

Comment: what is the structure of the table and what is the view definition?

Comment: Am I right in assuming that Visit_TotalVisits would contain 7 if it was 5 times yesterday and twice today ?

Comment: You have shown us the visits table, but I don't see the columns: Visit_TotalVisits and Visit_LastVisitDateOnly

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and that's where my problem originated - the original query won't pick up that person. The Visits_TotalVisits is a Count based on the Visits table, and Visit_LastVisitDateOnly is a MAX() based on visits, both drawn into View1.

Comment: You will have to query the visit journal to pick up this history. Check my answer

Comment: try using `PARTITION BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AccountID
FROM View1 v
INNER JOIN (SELECT AccountID
            FROM Visits
            WHERE Visit < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
            GROUP BY AccountID
            HAVING COUNT(1) = 5) hist ON v.AccountID = hist.AccountID
AND Visit_LastVisitDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Subquery visit_history will pick up all visitors who visited the shop exactly 5 times in the past.
Then it joins with the view that has last visit date. If last visit is today, means it was 6th, 7th, Nth or whatever, but the point is that 6th visit occured today.

Comment: Hi, I get the error Incorrect syntax near 'hist' with the code above.

Comment: Did you fill in your table names/columns correspondingly ?

Comment: Does the View1 have AccountID column at all? If it doesn't you need and additional join to fetch that info.

Comment: Yeah, I've replaced table/column names, but getting the error Incorrect syntax near 'hist'. And yes, the view does include AccountID.

Comment: oops, a bit syntax mistake. Updated

Comment: Thank you very much, this has given me the desired results - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

`SELECT Member_FullName, Branch_Name, Member_Email1, Account_Description, Visit_LastVisitDateOnly,
RANK() OVER   (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY Visit_ID DESC) AS Rank
FROM   View1
WHERE(Visit_TotalVisits = '6')
 AND (Rank = 6)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

with rank you can apply a ranking at a column ordered by an other column.
Maybe does not fit your structure right now, but you can tweak it a bit if you understand the ranking.

Comment: I get an error with this - Invalid column name 'Rank'

Comment: and your using : SQL server 2012 ?
( i do not know the exact columns that you have... )
Make sure you understand how the rank works from the microsoft website

Comment: You can't refer to RANK in the same scope, you need to wrap it in a subselect

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a stored procedure...

Create a temp table with an identity column on it, say "visitId".
Insert the visits into this temp table in the visit date order.

Select the one from the temp table where visitId = 6.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
Visit_TotalVisits = 6
```

by:

```
Visit_TotalVisits >= 6
```